# WIFI loss every 30 seconds, with frequent CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS since upgrading to 22.04

Tags: network-manager, 22.04

Ever since I upgraded to 22.04 my network adapter has been doing this weird thing where it disconnects from the Wi-Fi and automatically reconnects every 30 seconds. Sometimes, it'll refuse to reconnect, and I'll have to disable, and re-enable the internet in the top right corner. Whenever it refuses to reconnect a little question mark shows up on the wifi icon, and the `journalctl` is filled with continuous messages of `CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS` spamming every second.

Here's a copy of `journalctl` of just the last minute of continuous disconnecting and reconnecting.

```
May 05 18:42:45   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
May 05 18:42:45   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=MACADRESS reason=4 locally_generated=1
May 05 18:42:45   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 05 18:42:45   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765365.6223] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:42:45   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765365.6224] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:42:45   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765365.7057] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:42:45   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765365.7057] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: authenticate with MACADRESS
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with MACADRESS (SSID='HOMEWIFI' freq=2437 MHz)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6679] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: send auth to MACADRESS (try 1/3)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6679] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: Trying to associate with MACADRESS (SSID='HOMEWIFI' freq=2437 MHz)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6701] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6702] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: authenticated
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: associate with MACADRESS (try 1/3)
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from MACADRESS (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=76)
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: associated
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country element
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: Associated with MACADRESS
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6865] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6865] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.6866] device (wlo1): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7043] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7044] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7044] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7044] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7046] device (wlo1): ip:dhcp6: restarting
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7046] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7046] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7046] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed no lease
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7047] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7053] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7053] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:42:46   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:42:46   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:42:46   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with MACADRESS [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 05 18:42:46   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to MACADRESS completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7576] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:42:46   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765366.7581] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:42:46   kernel: wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by MACADRESS
May 05 18:42:47   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=-94 txrate=52000
May 05 18:42:47   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765367.6628] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed new lease
May 05 18:42:47   dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=818 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 05 18:42:47   systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 05 18:42:47   dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 05 18:42:47   systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 05 18:42:49   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765369.0521] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed new lease, address=192.168.100.11
May 05 18:42:59   systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 05 18:43:11   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
May 05 18:43:11   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=MACADRESS reason=4 locally_generated=1
May 05 18:43:11   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 05 18:43:11   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765391.5584] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:43:11   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765391.5585] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:43:11   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765391.6414] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:43:11   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765391.6414] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with MACADRESS (SSID='HOMEWIFI' freq=2437 MHz)
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: authenticate with MACADRESS
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6273] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6273] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: send auth to MACADRESS (try 1/3)
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: Trying to associate with MACADRESS (SSID='HOMEWIFI' freq=2437 MHz)
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6297] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6298] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: authenticated
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: associate with MACADRESS (try 1/3)
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: Associated with MACADRESS
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from MACADRESS (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=76)
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: associated
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country element
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6791] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6791] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6791] device (wlo1): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6963] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6963] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6964] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6964] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6965] device (wlo1): ip:dhcp6: restarting
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6966] dhcp6 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6966] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6966] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed no lease
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6966] dhcp6 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6971] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.6971] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:43:12   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:43:12   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:43:12   gnome-shell[1763]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with MACADRESS [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 05 18:43:12   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to MACADRESS completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.7704] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:43:12   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765392.7708] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:43:12   kernel: wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by MACADRESS
May 05 18:43:13   wpa_supplicant[864]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=-94 txrate=52000
May 05 18:43:13   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765393.6985] dhcp6 (wlo1): state changed new lease
May 05 18:43:13   dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=818 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 05 18:43:13   systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 05 18:43:13   dbus-daemon[817]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 05 18:43:13   systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 05 18:43:15   NetworkManager[818]: <info>  [1651765395.0435] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed new lease, address=192.168.100.11
May 05 18:43:25   systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I spend many hours on same problem with my laptop.

I am sure that this will not help everyone, this is my special case
On my Ubuntu automatically has been installed driver rtw88_8821ce, and i faced with CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS messages and unstable connection.

I change driver on [this](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce#wi-fi-not-working-for-kernel--59) and follow all instructions, this helps to me.
As far i can see somthin was wrong between Realtek Driver and linux kernel

Comment: This may be an answer if the info in the link was included here in this answer. The link may be gone in the future. You can refer to a link but include the info in the question.

Comment: @chili555 I wrote exactly this that, this is my SPECIAL CASE and need to look for a problem between the driver and the kernel

Comment: Nonetheless, it isn't an adequate answer to the original question about an Atheros adapter.